# Difficulty Parsing Ansible Output

Tags: ansible

[ansible 2.9.6, Ubuntu 20.04]

This seems pretty straightforward, but I keep getting an error message saying:

```
fatal: [192.168.254.100]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ipv4addrs.'host[0]'}}"}
```

Here's my ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: nios
  connection: local
  vars:
    nios_provider:
            host: 192.x.x.x
            username: xxx
            password: xxx
            wapi_version: "2.11.2"
            
  tasks:
    - name: Find client app server records
      set_fact:
        recs: "{{ lookup('nios', 'record:host', filter={'name~':'sdk' }, provider=nios_provider) }}"

    - name: check return
      debug:
         msg: "{{ recs }}"

    - name: get host name
      debug:
        var: ipv4addrs.'host[0]'
```

And here's the output:

```
TASK [check return] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.x.x.x] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "_ref": "record:host/ZG5zLmhvc3QkLl9kZWZhdWx0LmNvbS5lYWdsZWFjY2Vzcy5zZGstZDAwMQ:sdk-d001.somename.com/default",
            "ipv4addrs": [
                {
                    "_ref": "record:host_ipv4addr/ZG5zLmhvc3RfYWRkcmVzcyQuX2RlZmF1bHQuY29tLmVhZ2xlYWNjZXNzLnNkay1kMDAxLjEwLjcwLjAuMS4:10.70.0.1/sdk-d001.somename.com/default",
                    "configure_for_dhcp": false,
                    "host": "sdk-d001.somename.com",
                    "ipv4addr": "10.70.0.1"
                }
            ],
            "name": "sdk-d001.somename.com",
            "view": "default"
        },
        {
            "_ref": "record:host/ZG5zLmhvc3QkLl9kZWZhdWx0LmNvbS5lYWdsZWFjY2Vzcy5zZGstZDAwMg:sdk-d002.somename.com/default",
            "ipv4addrs": [
                {
                    "_ref": "record:host_ipv4addr/ZG5zLmhvc3RfYWRkcmVzcyQuX2RlZmF1bHQuY29tLmVhZ2xlYWNjZXNzLnNkay1kMDAyLjEwLjcwLjAuMi4:10.70.0.2/sdk-d002.somename.com/default",
                    "configure_for_dhcp": false,
                    "host": "sdk-d002.somename.com",
                    "ipv4addr": "10.70.0.2"
                }
            ],
            "name": "sdk-d002.somename.com",
            "view": "default"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [get host name] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.254.100]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ipv4addrs.'host[0]'}}"}
```

My objective is to find all of the host names beginning with (for example) "sdk". There may be 1 or several. And then I want to get the full name and ip address captured as variables. I have tried lots of different options: rec.ipv4addrs[0].host, ipv4addrs[0].host, rec.ipv4addrs[0].'host', rec.ipv4addrs[0].['host'] . . . but I cannot find the proper syntax.

This appears to be an array of dict blocks with an ipv4addrs array within it. So the first thing I tried was "ipv4addrs[0]['host']" with no joy.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think the indentation (spaces) with `host` and remaining attributes are off. Correct that and see

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting. I can't control the output, that's coming from the Infoblox API. Or are you saying I should somehow programmatically remove the space between "host": and "sdk.etc"?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make use of a variable called `ipv4addrs`, but you
haven't defined any variables with that name. From the previous
`debug` task you apparently have a variable named `recs`, which is a
list of dictionaries each of which contains an `ipv4addrs` attribute.

If you wanted to look up the `host` attribute for each record in
`recs`, you could write something like this:

```
    - name: get host name
      debug:
        var: item.ipv4addrs[0].host
      loop: "{{ recs }}"
```

If you wanted the `ipv4addrs.host` value from the first record, you
could write:

```
    - name: get host name
      debug:
        var: recs[0].ipv4addrs[0].host
```

---

The error you're seeing stems from the fact that the expression
`ipv4addrs.'host[0]'` doesn't make any sense; that's not a syntax that
Ansible supports. You can't use a string with dot-notation like that.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but both your suggestions produce the error "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED".    - name: get host by name
      debug:
        var: item.ipv4addrs.host
      loop: "{{ recs }}"


    - name: get host
      debug:
        var: recs[0].ipv4addrs.host      TASK [get IP addr] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.x.x.x] => {
    "recs[0].ipv4addrs.host": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Comment: Then replace the variable name with one you've actually defined. In your question, you show a variable named `recs`.

Comment: Turns out this works: recs[0].ipv4addrs[0].host. The issue, tho, is only half solved because I don't know how many recs I will find.

Comment: Good catch on the missing array index. I've updated the answer. What's your goal? Do you want the first hostname? The last? Are you trying to do something with all of them?

Comment: I am sending a query to a DNS box (Infoblox) looking for all host names that are prefixed with a client ID (3 characters). I then need to create a NAT entry for each one I find. There may only be 1 or there may be 10. I need to assign a variable to each host/IP address I find and pass them to another playbook.